# MySQL: Select specific strings and replace on several locations

Tags: mysql, sql, select, replace

The table have several columns. One of them is 'video'. There are many rows, all cells contain one string. The string should get more accessories. They contain different names for the label and the url, expect the 'XYREE -' inside the label, which never changes.

This is the wanted string:

```
{"label":"XYREE - A small title",
"link":"http://google.com/hasAlengthOf50symbols"}
```

This is the actual string:

```
XYREE - A small title |-|http://google.com/hasAlengthOf50symbols
```

This was my try to find the wanted rows and to replace a part of it.

```
SELECT *  FROM `items` WHERE `video` 
NOT REGEXP '{"label":"XYREE' REPLACE(video, 'XYREE', '{"label":"XYREE')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS is it? I'm guessing MySQL...

Comment: You want to update table , replace ACTUAL string With WANTED string in column video .

Comment: I updated the question. The strings are dissimilar.

Comment: It's still very unclear what you actually want. Please 1) State clearly do you want to change values in the table or you just want to select augmented values 2) provide a few rows of sample data with ***dissimilar*** values in a tabular form 3) provide the desired outcome again in a tabular form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in single step but for clarity i replacing in multiple steps.

```
Update items
Set video = replace(video,'XYREE','{"label":"XYREE')


Update items
Set video = replace(video,'|-|','","link":"')



Update items
Set video = concat(video,'"}')
```

Comment: Yes thanks you were already right above. How to do this with the ending "} symbols in mysql?

Comment: What you want to do with ending symbol , using concat() I have added it to end of string

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT id, CONCAT('{"label":"', 
                  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(video, '|-|', 1)), 
                  '","link:"', 
                  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(video, '|-|', -1)), '"}') video
  FROM items
 WHERE ...
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |                                                                             VIDEO |
|----|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | {"label":"XYREE - A small title","link:"http://google.com/hasAlengthOf50symbols"} |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68c27/2)** demo

---

If you need to actually replace (update) values in your table

```sql
UPDATE items
   SET video = CONCAT('{"label":"', 
                      TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(video, '|-|', 1)), 
                      '","link:"', 
                      TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(video, '|-|', -1)), '"}')
 WHERE ...
```